# object name for checkbox and sql command to populate more than one table

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, checkbox

I have an database with 3 tables, I want to add data to it in my java aplication...

```
String command1 = "INSERT INTO Drivers (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES" + drivID + FName + LName;
```

Can I use this command to enter data in all 3 tables or do I have to create 3 commands like this to use in the following prepared statement

```
PreparedStatement p = conn.getStatement(command1);
```

Allso in my tables I have checkboxes and strings
I made String variables as follow

```
String drivID = txtid.getText();
```

Can someone tell me what the object name for a checkbox is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String command1 = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", tableName, ID, fName, lName);
PreparedStatement p = conn.getStatement(command1);
```

Although, for your example, I see no reason why you cannot use a java.sql.Statement instead of a PreparedStatement.